# Problem with js files path, NuxtJS+AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, nuxt.js

Tried to deploy my nuxt app to aws lambda.
Read this articles:

https://medium.com/@fernalvarez/serverless-side-rendering-with-aws-lambda-nuxtjs-b94d15782af5

https://dzone.com/articles/a-crash-course-on-serverless-side-rendering-with-v

All works but have some js errors in console. Tried multiple variants for "router.base" and "build.publicPath" config with no luck.

Here is my env:

> nuxt.config.js: https://pastecode.xyz/view/69ad1f00
>
> package.json: https://pastecode.xyz/view/2401a6d2
>
> server.js: https://pastecode.xyz/view/48012477
>
> handler.js: https://pastecode.xyz/view/b59848a5
>
> serverless.yml: https://pastecode.xyz/view/5916f406

So, when I visit deployed app, all is nice except errors in js console:

[image: errors]

As I checked in html code, the path for this js is generated as:

> https://*******.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/_nuxt/7881ea044902e4092627.js

which is 404, BUT! this one is present:

> https://*******.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dev/_nuxt/7881ea044902e4092627.js

You can see additional /dev/ which I added manually.
So, what should I do to make it loaded? What am I missing in config (and in which one)?

Comment: Seems like second `dev` in there is the one defined in your config file. First `dev` is the stage name for the API. That seems to be the only explanation for your described behavior.

    `build: {
      publicPath: '/dev/_nuxt/',
      //more code
    }`

Comment: @ASR thanks, but what should I do with my config?

Comment: Have you tried setting `publicPath` as `/_nuxt/`? Or maybe you can append the URL path `serverless` returns with you `publicPath`.

Comment: @asr yeah, already tried. i tried these variants:

router.base = ‘/’ && publicPath = ‘/dev/_nuxt/’
router.base = ‘/’ && publicPath = ‘/_nuxt/’
router.base = ‘/dev/’ && publicPath = ‘/dev/_nuxt/’
router.base = ‘/dev/’ && publicPath = ‘/_nuxt/’

neither one working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to try to explain what happens:

Probably the API Gateway is redirecting your application to run with the path "/dev", so when we access "/dev" it redirects inside to our Nuxt application and it returns as 200, and when Nuxt try to get the files it doesn't add the path "/dev".
But if you change the "publicPath" to "/dev/_nuxt/", then you can access your file with the path "/dev/dev/_nuxt", the first "dev" probably is API Gateway adding it, and when your Nuxt app try to get the file it goes to "/dev/_nuxt/" and you get 404.

I couldn't really fix it, but if I start using the real domain I won't have those problems because API Gateway will stop adding this "/dev" to my path. To do it you can use the plugin to serverless "serverless-domain-manager".

I also created an article about how to create a Nuxt Application with Typescript, you can check there how to do it: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nuxt-typescript-koa-serverless-edison-harada